# How to retrieve related videos of a video using YoutubeAPI v3

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm making an app using Youtube API v3 to retrieve stuff on youtube. When open a video on Youtube, there are some related videos of the video on the right side.

[image]

The videos on the red rectangle

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Youtube api already provided method to get related videos

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId

For example

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId={VIDEO_ID}&type=video&key={API_KEY}